# Invalid default value for 'column'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

When upgrading to Laravel 5.4 and MySQL 5.7, migrations are not working anymore and I'm getting this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'updated_at' (SQL: create table `tracker_paths` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primar
  y key, `path` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp not null, `updated_at` timestamp not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB ROW_FO
  RMAT=DYNAMIC) (SQL: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'updated_at' (SQL: create table `tracker_paths` (`id` bigint unsigned not null a
  uto_increment primary key, `path` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp not null, `updated_at` timestamp not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci en
  gine = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC))
```

What should I do?

Comment: The corresponding migration code should also be included.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to sql mode [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](https://www.noelherrick.com/blog/mysql-strict_all_tables-vs-strict_trans_tables), so you have three options:

1) Fix your migrations.

2) Change strict to false in your mysql connection:

```
'mysql' => $database = [
    ...
    'strict' => false,
    ...
],
```

Which will disable all those sql modes:

```
set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

3) Set custom modes, removing STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

```
'mysql' => $database = [
    ...
    'modes' => "set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'",
    ...
],
```